# Inserting unique value from one table to another table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have table with attributes ticket number and category. I need to insert data from this table into another table with ticket number as primary key.

What I need is if table 1 contains two entry for same ticket number, than I have to update the second table.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Table structure pls.., if there are duplicate entry which one to select?(do all columns have same value?)

Comment: Please share Tables structure and what you have tried in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use triggers to do this. All that is needed is that after each insert on the first table you need to scan for second instance of the ticket in the table. If its present then insert a record using insert statement in the second table.

Comment: i haven't studied trigger. is there any other way

Comment: I guess not. Thats the reason why triggers are built for. You would want to handle on the database level. Here is the link for it. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html